# How to set Menu Help Text in Window Custom ShellExtension popup menu Item

Tags: contextmenu, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I need to set the menu help text of my shell context menu popup menu item just like winzip shellContext menu. I tried IContextMenu_GetCommandString but it is only setting menu help for sub menus of my main popup menu. Please help me and let me know how to set the menu help for my main poup menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you haven't solved this already, here is what worked for me.

You need to insert your popup menu into the explorer menu using `InsertMenuItem`, as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ctxextsubmenu.aspx). This allows you to give your popup menu an ID.

The shell passes that ID into IContextMenu_GetCommandString when querying the items, by way of checking for that ID you can return any help string you need.

However, it may simply not be displayed if you right-click on a folder in the (left) folders pane of explorer, and not in the files pane to the right. On my system, if one or more elements are selected in the files pane, the properties (type, size, name and some more stuff) are displayed in the status bar, even if I right-click on any folder in the folders pane.
This seems to be standard behaviour - at least on my system it's the same for all installed custom extensions and even for the default explorer menus.